# Connecting to the internet Via USB on Ubuntu 12.10 issue

Tags: 12.10, internet, mobile-broadband

Yesterday the connection worked now when I plug in my iPhone its displaying the connecting icon then stops and carries on.

I have no Internet connection; only my phone, which means I can't install packages. What do I need to do?